# Unable to set password for mysql

Tags: mysql

i am installing mysql in my fedora 17 machine and i am getting the following error while trying to set my username and password.

```
mysqladmin -u root password xyz

mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

I am getting this error while setting up the username and password the first time itself.

Please help.

Comment: try: mysqladmin -u root password “xyz”

Comment: still getting the same error.

Comment: try just `mysql -u root` and does it go through ?